# If a function arg supports numpy arrays how should its type annotations, originally a built-in, be re-annotated?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

As a motivating example, let's say our goal is to have one function that add two variables containing either a single integer or single integer array (each). As two separate functions the typing annotations is trivially:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


def add_two_builtin_ints(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


def add_two_ints_numpy(
    a: npt.NDArray[np.integer], b: npt.NDArray[np.integer]
) -> npt.NDArray[np.integer]:
    return a + b

# What should be the annotations here?
def add_two_ints(a: ?, b: ?) -> ?:
    """Add two integers or array of integers."""
    return a + b
```

What is the proper way according to PEP and typing tools provided in Python and NumPy so that `add_ints` can take both built-in integer and numpy integer arrays?

---

The above example is only for the integers, my confusion lies not knowing how to deal with other args that also allows numpy arrays (e.g., supports ints and floats, supports any numeric).

Comment: It looks like you already have a type: `npt.NDArray[np.int_]`.  What's the problem with using that same type as the annotation for your function parameters?  Or is the idea that you want the function to accept *any* objects that can be added?  (That'd be a good use for a `Protocol`.)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I think you'd probably want to create a type alias `Addable` or something which represents all types you plan to use with that function, and which support that operation, so you might have `Addable = int | npt.NDArray` and then you'd annotate `add(a: Addable, b: Addable) -> Addable`. Would be best to use generics, too, so that the return type is consistent. But right now, with a function called `add_two_ints` you WOULDN'T overload it (at least without renaming it to something more general).

Comment: What behavior are you trying to statically guarantee? Do you want to annotate that function so that it's valid to pass any type(s) that can be reasonably added? Do you care if `a` and `b` are the same type? How do you want the return type to relate to the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: In "plain" python, without the static type checking, this function will work with anything that implements the `__add__` - not only ints and floats, but also strings, lists, tuples, and of course numpy arrays.

Comment: @Samwise, If you did that, type checkers (at least Pylance), will complain whenever you pass in an `int`, it is not a `npt.NDArray[np.int_]`. The intention is to be compatible with both.

Comment: Your example didn't include a case where you were calling it with ints, which is why I asked for clarification.  :)

Comment: The answer that @ddejohn is my intention, however having to build generics for all sorts is pain. The `add_two_ints()` seems to not be a good example of my conundrum. A better example may be an type-annotated `np.mean` which supports **at least** built-in numerics (`int`, `float`, `complex`, etc) and numpy types (`np.integer`, `np.floating`, `np.complexfloating`)

Comment: Many of the `numpy` functions, call `asanyarray(a)` on the argument (if it isn't already a numpy array).  That is why python numerics work, as well as lists.

Comment: Should type annotations try to capture all the flexibility of builtin python and numpy functions and operators?  Or just the cases specific to your own code?

Comment: @hpaulj Just this example will do. I think `asanyarray` is a good fix to typing ambiguity as you allow the input to be `npt.ArrayLike` and output to be `npt.NDArray[Any]` with the side-effect that the output type is the same as input. A non-issue is it allows non-integer input (duck typing is fine).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to be able to handle *any* objects that can be added together to produce an object of the same type, that's a good use case for `Protocol` and `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

AddableType = TypeVar("AddableType", bound="Addable")

class Addable(Protocol):
    def __add__(self: AddableType, other: AddableType) -> AddableType: ...


def add_two(a: AddableType, b: AddableType) -> AddableType:
    return a + b


add_two(1, 2)    # ok
add_two([], [])  # ok
add_two(1, [])   # error
```

With this annotation, you'll get an error if you pass in two types that can't be added according to the protocol definition (e.g. `int` and `list` both implement `__add__`, but it's not valid to add one to the other).  The return type is also reflected correctly:

```
reveal_type(add_two(1, 2))  # Revealed type is "builtins.int*"
```

Comment: There's not much need for two separate variables `Addable` and `AddableType`. You can hint `Addable.__add__` with `Addable` (using either strings, the `annotations` future, or wait until Python 3.11 when `annotations` is the default, mandatory behavior), and hint `add_two` with `Addable` as well.

Comment: The one thing you *might* want to make more specific is whether `__add__` always returns a value of the same type as `self` and/or `other`, or if it's possible to return a different type altogether.

Comment: I've did updated my question to be more clea and I did not see your answer before then.  As it stands, this does more than my intentions (e.g., to be able to add two integers or two numpy integer arrays).

Comment: @chepner The purpose of `AddableType` with a *bound* of `Addable` is to allow you to specify that it's the *same* type in a given context, rather than two arbitrary types that both implement the protocol.  If you just use the `Addable` protocol directly, it'll accept `add_two(1, [])` even though that results in a runtime `TypeError`.

Comment: Ah, right. Wondered what that whooshing sound was when I typed my comment...