# Mypy: Typing two list of int or str to be added together

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that merge two list of either int or str.
There cannot be a situation when the two list are being of different types.

it is defined by the following code:

```py
AddableList = ...


def add_arrays(array: AddableList, array2: AddableList) -> AddableList:
    if len(array) != len(array2):
        raise ValueError

    return [a + b for a, b in zip(array, array2)]
```

When typing `AddableList`, using `List[int]`
`mypy: Success: no issues`

When typing `AddableList`, using `List[str]`
`mypy: Success: no issues`

However, mypy will return the following error

```
error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
note: Both left and right operands are unions
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 333 source files)
```

when using typing correctly the lists with `AddableList = List[Union[int, str]]`

Finally, when trying to type `AddableList` to `Union[List[int], List[str]]`, mypy errors with:

```
error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("object")
```

What typing should i use to resolve this issue?

Comment: just as @Mark mentioned, typing does not actually enforce not being able to pass on one hand a string and on the other an int

Comment: I misread @M.Ionut It looks like the lists will always be the same type.

Comment: @Mark yes the list are always both the same type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TypeVar` that will resolve to one type or the other (but not both at once within the same context):

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

Addable = TypeVar("Addable", str, int)


def add_arrays(array: List[Addable], array2: List[Addable]) -> List[Addable]:
    if len(array) != len(array2):
        raise ValueError

    return [a + b for a, b in zip(array, array2)]

reveal_type(add_arrays([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]))    # List[int]
reveal_type(add_arrays(["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]))  # List[str]
reveal_type(add_arrays([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]))  # error
```

The final line throws an error because there's no type that `Addable` can resolve to:

```
test.py:14: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "add_arrays"
```

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot i thought of using a bound with TypeVar which didn't get me on the right track, didn't thought on using it that way!

Comment: For a fancier version that supports *any* kind of "addable" object, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993700/3799759